# How to prove this inequality in convex optimization?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-cone

Suppose that $C$ is a proper convex cone, and $C^0$ is the dual cone. Then we have the following inequality $$\sup _{\|z\|_{2}=1, z \in C} h^{T} z \leq \inf _{z \in C^{\circ}}\|h-z\|_{2}.$$
I tried to prove this by writing out the dual of the original problem, but ran into some issues.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z \in C$ with $\|z\|_2 = 1$ and $v \in C^\circ$ be given. Then,
$$
h^\top z \le (h - v)^\top z \le \|h-v\|_2.$$

This implies your inequality.

Comment: This is not true? If $v\in C^\circ$ then $\langle v,z\rangle \geq 0$.

Comment: @TonyS.F.: It depends on the definition of $C^\circ$. I used $C^\circ = \{ v  \mid v^\top z \le 0 \forall z \in C\}$.

Comment: @GavinZZZ: What do you mean by "original problem"?

Comment: @gerw that is not the dual cone, that is the polar cone. See, for example, the book by Bauschke and Combettes or the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_cone_and_polar_cone

Comment: @TonyS.F.: I know the distinction between dual and polar cone. However, with the "real dual cone", the inequality in the question is wrong. Hence, the OP seems to use the wrong notion of 'dual cone'.

Comment: @gerw that's a good point. Indeed, the notation matches the convention for polar cone despite using the wrong name.

Comment: Can you show your efforts (by editing your question)? Then, we can help you with your issues.